# Elusive bug when trying to read data from record into program(C++)

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to make a program that reads and writes data to a data file. For some reason I can't figure out, it can't read a char from the file only the name and numbers name. I need the char so I can display a list of items.

The data in the file is a record, the struct is this and the error occurs when trying to get a char.

```
struct Data
{
    char Genre;
    string Productname;
    int Numberofproducts;
    int Numberofproductsleft;
    int Numberofproductssold;
    bool Morethantwo;
    bool Noticeseen;
    float price;
};

//Lists genre to choose from
string listofgenres[] = {"1) Book", "2) Movie", "3) Other", "4) Delete Entry" };
```

This is the code inside the void function I named input, that writes the data to the file. This is for a book, there are three other options which is why they have a char to identify what genre the data is.

```
Data put;
int choice;
string genrechosen;
ofstream F;

int count = 0;

    cout<<"What genre is the item? (Type the option or enter 1,2, or 3): "<<endl;
    while(count < logs)
    {
        cout<<listofgenres[count]<<endl;
        count++;
    }

    cin >> genrechosen;

    genrechosen = validate(genrechosen, 'I');

    if(genrechosen == "1" || genrechosen == "Books" || genrechosen == "books" || genrechosen == "Book" || genrechosen == "book" || genrechosen == "B" || genrechosen == "b")
    {
        F.open(filename, ios::out|ios::app|ios::binary);
        put.Genre = '~';

        cout<<"What is the name of the book: "<<endl;
        cin >> put.Productname;

        cout<<"How many "<<put.Productname<<" do you have: "<<endl;
        cin >> put.Numberofproducts;
        neg(put.Numberofproducts);

        cout<<"How much are you selling "<<put.Productname<<" for? (If you don't know , just put 0. Don't put a $): "<<endl;
        cin >> put.price;
        neg(put.price);

        put.Numberofproductssold = 0;
        put.Numberofproductsleft = put.Numberofproducts;

        if(put.Numberofproducts >= 2)
            put.Morethantwo = true;
        else
            put.Morethantwo = false;

        put.Noticeseen = false;

        F.write( (const char *)&put , sizeof(put));
        F.close();
    }
```

I have used reinterpret_cast<char*> and it failed which is why F.write is like that.

The error comes when trying to read data from the file(in the void function I called Modify), I also tried just using a regular text file and still encountered the same problem.

```
     Data change;
     string answer;
     char genrechosen;
     int sold;
     int continuee;
     int continued;
     int passedrecords = 0;
     vector <int> position;

f1.open(filename, ios::in|ios::out|ios::ate|ios::binary);

    int count = 1;

    cout<<"What genre is the item you are looking for? "<<endl;
    for(int val = 0; val <= logs; val++)
        cout<<listofgenres[val]<<endl;

    cin >> answer;

    //Validates input
    if(answer != "4" || answer != "Delete Entry" || answer != "delete entry" || answer != "Delete" || answer != "delete" || answer != "D" || answer != "d" )
        answer = validate(answer, 'I'); // Uses I for the char variable because they both use same list, so there is no point in creating new char for it.

    //Allows for list of only that genre to be shown
    else if(answer == "1" || answer == "Books" || answer == "books" || answer == "Book" || answer == "book" || answer == "B" || answer == "b")
        genrechosen = '~';

    else if(answer == "2" || answer == "Movies" || answer == "movies" || answer == "Movie" || answer == "movie" || answer == "M" || answer == "m")
        genrechosen = '!';

    else if(answer == "3" || answer == "Other" || answer == "other" || answer == "O" || answer == "o")
        genrechosen = '@';
    else
        genrechosen = '_';

    //Displays List of items in that genre
    if(genrechosen == bs)
        cout<<"Which book's data will you be modifying? (Type in the number):"<<endl;
    if(genrechosen == ms)
        cout<<"Which movie's data will you be modifying? (Type in the number):"<<endl;
    if(genrechosen == orr)
        cout<<"What item's data will you be modifying? (Type in the number):"<<endl;
    if(genrechosen == de)
    {
        deleterec();
        return;
    }

    //Read records until eof
    while( f1.read( (char *)&change, sizeof(change)) )
    {
       if(change.Genre == genrechosen)
       {
            cout<<count<<") "<<change.Productname<<endl;
            count++;
            position.push_back(passedrecords);
       }

       (Personal comment)/* We need to know exactly what record in the file matches that genre, that way when the users chooses a number of the list, we can go and find that exact record. We don't want only 2 records to show up and then conclude the user wants the second record when they actually want the 37th record.*/

       passedrecords++;

    }
```

Tl;Dr;

The problem is the while loop only iterates once, when there is more than one record. Also change. Genre never has an actual value, so no records are displayed. I can't read the name or char data, only double/integers. The C++ book I am reading says use binary files for different data types, is that wrong?? Thank you and sorry its so long. I am using codeblocks compiler btw.

Edit 1: I am coming across this error after writing structure one at a time:

```
f1.read( (char *)&change.Genre, sizeof(change.Genre));
uint32_t size = change.Productname.length();
f1.read( (char *)&size, sizeof(size)); 
f1.read( change.Productname.data() , size); //Problematic Line
f1.read( (const char *)&change.Numberofproducts, sizeof(change.Numberofproducts));
f1.read( ( const char *)&change.Numberofproductsleft, sizeof(change.Numberofproductsleft));
f1.read( ( const char *)&change.Numberofproductssold, sizeof(change.Numberofproductssold));
f1.read( ( const char *)&change.Morethantwo, sizeof(change.Morethantwo));
f1.read( ( const char *)&change.Noticeseen, sizeof(change.Noticeseen));
f1.read( ( const char *)&change.price, sizeof(change.price));
```

Gives me error `Invalid conversion from const char to char`.

Comment: Writing out a binary record used to be the way to do it. But these days using text is a better idea. Structured text such as JSON or XML is even better. If you *were* going to use binary then something such as protobuf or ASN.1 is a better choice than directly writing out C structs.

Comment: Thank you, changing string to char[100] worked for now since i didn't understand resizing strings. However, I will read up on it and learn how to do it. Thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String, which like any object that might contain pointers, can't be written  with `fwrite` for later safe reconstruction. 
The quick-and-dirty fix (usually not recommended) is to replace:

```
string Productname;
```

with

```
 char Productname[100];
```

Or, better, write one field at a time. The string field can be written as size+characters, like this:

```
 F.write( (const char *)&put.Genre, sizeof(put.Genre)); 
 uint32_t size = put.Productname.length();
 F.write( (const char *)&size, sizeof(size)); 
 F.write(put.Productname.data(), size); 
 F.write( (const char *)&put.Numberofproducts, sizeof(put.Numberofproducts)); 
//... and so on
```

Reading should be done the same way.

**Note**: the process of writing and reading objects to and from files is usually called serialization and deserialization. For example [boost serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

**Note 2:** For file-format portability, it is better to write `int32_t`, `uint32_t`, `int64_t`, ..., rather than plain `int` or `long`. This is because `long` (and similar) have different number of bytes on different systems.

If you plan to use anything other than a PC, you should also note that different systems may have different byte order (big or little endian). This difference in ordering makes serializing even  `uint32_t` non-portable across such systems. For portability, it is better to break `uint32_t` objects into bytes by bit-operation, and serialize these bytes.

For signed types things are even more complicated, since the smallest possible `int32_t` value can be different on some specialized systems. Fortunately, theses are not very common.

Comment: So i would have to use that uint32_t size for each variable in the structure?? Also thank you very much.

Comment: @AdamsBrian not necessarily uint32_t. You can use int, long, float, char, and so on. The advantage of int32_t, int16_t, etc. is that it will work on both 32 and 64 bit systems (read/write on different systems). This is imperfect yet, since it won't be possible to read/write on systems with different byte order

Comment: @AdamsBrian the size is required for objects of variable length like `string`. You can have a similar problem with `int` if you transport the files around because [`int` can be any size 2 bytes or larger](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types). This is why Michael is suggesting types like `int32` where the size is guaranteed. You also have to watch out for [a little thing called endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: I still have a lot to learn about C++ I see. Thank you guys so much, this is truly insightful and I'm grateful

Comment: @AdamsBrian I have added a note clarifying some of these things at the end of the answer

Comment: thank you, i will research this in depth. I am just now starting to read about templates and stacks , so this is something I will start to research as well. Will be extremely helpful in the future

Comment: You can't read a string like that. You need to resize it first, before reading into str.data(), otherwise this is undefined behavior. You can read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data